# It is not recognising a php variable as nothing appears on echo

Tags: php, mysqli, bind

in my code below it is not able to recognise the variable `$userid`, this variable determines the id of the teacher logged in but in the mysqli code it is not able to determine the `$userid` when I echo it. But it does know the user is logged in by its `$userid`. So my question is that in the mysqli why is it unable to find the `$userid`? Please look at comment in mysqli `bind_param()` setion and this is where the problem is.

Below is the code, both php and mysqli:

Let me state that member.php is the script which contains the `$userid` info:

```
    <?php
     session_start();

        include('member.php');

    ...

        function PickSession()
        {

            //Get data from database
            $sessionquery = "
                SELECT s.SessionId, SessionName, s.TeacherId
                FROM Session s
                INNER JOIN Session_Complete sc ON sc.SessionId = s.SessionId
                WHERE
                (ModuleId = ? AND Complete = ? AND s.TeacherId = ?)
                ORDER BY SessionName 
                ";
            $complete = 1;

            global $mysqli;
            $sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
            // You only need to call bind_param once
            $sessionqrystmt->bind_param("iii",$moduleId, $complete, $userid);//it doesn't recognse $userid
            // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
            $sessionqrystmt->execute(); 
            $sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionName,$dbTeacherId);
            $sessionqrystmt->store_result();
            $sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();  

echo $userid; //nothing displayed in this echo
    ...

            if ((isset($username)) && (isset($userid))){ //user is successfully logged in

            include('teachername.php');

    ...

        <?php


        ShowAssessment(); // Show information



            }else{ 

    echo "Please Login to Access this Page | <a href='./teacherlogin.php'>Login</a>";

    }

            ?>
```

member.php script:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['teacherid'])) {

      $userid = $_SESSION['teacherid'];

  }

if (isset($_SESSION['teacherusername'])) {

      $username = $_SESSION['teacherusername'];

  }

        ?>
```

Comment: is the variable $_SESSION['teacherid'] set.? even if it is set  you need to use `global $userid` if you need to access that variable in the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialised the `$userid` variable, you have to set the value for binding the variable in query otherwise it will take `NULL` value for that variable.

```
$userid = "value";
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("iii",$moduleId, $complete, $userid);
```

The `$userid` variable is not accessible in `PickSession()`. So the suggestion is either make `$userid` as global or pass it as parameter in function.

Comment: its initialized on member.php and he has included the file

Comment: yeah i am agree that it is intialised in member.php but not passed this value in function `PickSession()`. So he has to pass it as argument or make this variable as `global`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar That's better, +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

may be because `session_start()` is missing

Comment: I do have session_start(), sorry forgotton include it

Answer (score 0):

You have not access to `$userid` in your function. Things that you can do:

Declare `$userid` as global variable (Not recomended)

```
function PickSession() {
    global $userid;
    // and the rest of the function here
}
```

Pass `$userid` as a parameter to function `PickSession`

Answer (score 0):

In your `PickSession` function, `$userid` has no value befause you haven't defined it, you should pass the variable through to the function when you call it, for example;

```
function PickSession($userid)
{
    ...
}

// Now call PickSession with the variable assigned:
PickSession($userid);
```